# Are the Windows8 internal event handler argument naming conventions as random as they seem?

Tags: event-handling, windows-8

After adding a Search Contract to a project, in App.xaml.cs, I see both this:

```
private async void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
```

(IOW, "e" for event args) and also this:

```
protected override void OnSearchActivated(Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.SearchActivatedEventArgs args)
```

("args" for the event args).

Is there some method to their madness (no pun intended), IOW is there a pattern/standard we should be following when we create event handlers? If so, what is it?

Comment: You can name your parameters whatever you like.  Just pick something reasonable.  Both `args` and `e` are perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `e` and `args` are commonly used variable names for event arguments.  Method parameter names need to be comprehensible and thus using a commonly used name for the event arguments is a good idea.  Beyond that I don't think there is any particular convention at play.